# Firebase .validate error

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a Firebase database organised as follows.

[image: Organization of my database]

As you can see, it is an array of dictionaries (each dictionary containing two entries, 'text' and 'tag').

It contains contains the following rules. What I wish to do is make sure that the newData contains a String called 'text' and a String called 'tag'.

```
{
   "rules": {
     ".read": "auth != null",

     ".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()",

       //Can write only Array with text and tag
     ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['text', 'tag'])",
     "$other": {
        ".validate": false
     },
     "text": {
       ".validate": "newData.isString()"
     },
     "tag": {
       ".validate": "newData.isString()"
     }
   }
 }
```

When I give it the following JSON, it says that 'the simulated writing was denied' on line 10 ( `".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['text', 'tag'])",` ).

The JSON file:

```
 {
    "3": {
        "text": "text message",
        "tag": "this is a tag"
    }
}
```

How should I write my rules?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining your validation rule one level too high. Right now you validate that the entire database has children `tag` and `text`, which it doesn't. Instead you want to validate that each child node under the root has these children, which requires that you define a `$` variable rule like this:

```
{
   "rules": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     "$childid": {
       ".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()",

       //Can write only Array with text and tag
       ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['text', 'tag'])",
       "$other": {
        ".validate": false
       },
       "text": {
         ".validate": "newData.isString()"
       },
       "tag": {
         ".validate": "newData.isString()"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```